# How to make intellij import the latest version of my jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have project-A which depends on project-B. Now whenever I change something in project-B I need to do a reimport of project-A , so that the changes I made in project-B is imported in. Reimporting the entire project is taking a lot of time. Is there anyway I can make this process faster ?

I just want to get the project-B changes in project-A

Comment: You can `mvn install` project-B into your local maven repository and it to your project-A dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Create a project which contains both projects as modules, reference through Maven one to the other, that will cause a build of both on compilation of the root

See:

- [Multiple Modules Guide for Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)
- [Maven Multi Module Project](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But that would need a change in my project structure. Can we do it without that ?

Comment: If you add a maven dependency and each change in ProjA will cause an update in the pom file, for the version of ProjA - this will do